# xslt escaped xml inside xml

Tags: xml, xslt, escaping

I'm dooing a xslt parsing of a xml document to HMTL. I'm only selecting some relevant elements. Problem is that this xml doc contains escaped xml and that I have to parse some of those to my output.

I'm using `disable-output-escaping="yes"` to retrieve the content of `<ApprovedData>` but i can not see a way that this resulting xml can be again accessed from my xsl.

How can I construct a template that is referring to the `<documentid>` element inside `<ApprovedData>`

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Message><Method>OCESIIJS</Method>
<ApprovedData>&lt;transfers&gt;
    &lt;transfer action="approve"&gt;
        &lt;amount&gt;0&lt;/amount&gt;
        &lt;type&gt;Document&lt;/type&gt;
        &lt;hostref&gt;0&lt;/hostref&gt;
        &lt;cdnidfr&gt;0&lt;/cdnidfr&gt;
        &lt;documentid&gt;zzzzyyyyxxxx;/documentid&gt;
        &lt;signdocument&gt;true&lt;/signdocument&gt;
    &lt;/transfer&gt;
&lt;/transfers
&gt;
</ApprovedData>
<Message>
.....`
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? With Saxon 9.7 for instance you have access to the XPath 3.0 function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml. Depending on your XSLT processor you might also be able to write an extension function in C# (e.g. with XslCompiledTransform) or JScript (e.g. with MSXML).

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29205050/3016153

Comment: If it is valid XML, you could simply unescape it using `sed` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you intend to do with the `documentid`, this might or might not be helpful:

```
  <xsl:template match="Message">
    <xsl:variable name="documentid" select="./ApprovedData/text()" />
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($documentid, 'documentid&gt;'), ';/documentid')" />
  </xsl:template>
```

You might have to change the strings, since you appear to have cut off the `&lt` after the document id.